# sending phpmailer on data deletion

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmailer

I have a form that adds a user to a mysql database table and emails the new information to a address (working).

Now I have a form that is used to delete records from the table but I am unable to get it to email the old users data before it deletes it.

for example if the user deletes the id 45 from the table, an email must be sent saying "A user was deleted from the table: 'Name','Phone','Extension'"

code for the delete.php:

```
<?php
require ("database.php");  

?> 

<?php


$this_Stud_ID =$_REQUEST['id'];

    // sending query
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$this_Stud_ID'")
    or die(mysql_error());          


    if($_POST['action'])

header("Location: index.php");
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['php_self'] ?>" method="post">
Enter ID Number :<br><input type="text" name="id"><br />
<br><input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete!">
<br> <br>
<h3>
<a href="index.php"> Main Menu </a> 
</h3>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must fetch user data before delete.
Do something like this

```
<?php
require ("database.php");
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && (int)$_REQUEST['id']>0){
        $this_Stud_ID =(int)$_REQUEST['id'];
        $user_record=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('select * from users where id=' . $this_Stud_ID));
        //now send an email to user or to anyone and use $user_record as user data
        $to='';
        $subject='';
        $message='';
        $headers='';
        $mail_status=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        if($mail_status){
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$this_Stud_ID'")or die(mysql_error());          
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['php_self'] ?>" method="post">
    Enter ID Number :<br><input type="text" name="id"><br />
    <br><input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete!">
    <br> <br>
    <h3><a href="index.php"> Main Menu </a></h3>
</form>
```

Comment: using phpmailer will still be fine?

Answer (score 0):

Look like the code isn't complete ! 
On form submit first fetch the data with `WHERE id = $this_Stud_ID`
and execute 
`mail("yourname@domain.com","Subject","phone no name  ..etc");`
then you can execute

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$this_Stud_ID'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Please post your complete code !

Comment: So.  You are not written the code for mail in delete.php right? Check @GauravRai's answer.

Comment: correct i will be trying the answer Gaurav gave above and see if that works

Comment: im using phpmailer by the way